# What is the best algorithm for finding a $g \in S_n$ which $a^g=b$ for given $a, b \in S_n$

Tags: algorithms, permutations, gap

What is the best algorithm for finding a $g \in S_n$ which $a^g=b$ for given $a, b \in S_n$, where $S_n$ is a symmetric group and $a$ and $b$ have same cycle type?

Question 2: Is there any command in GAP that can find such $g$?

Comment: This is not always possible. Its guaranteed in cyclic groups.

Comment: Find the disjoint cycles in $a$ and $b$. Since you assume that they have the same cycle type, you can just match the cardinality of each cycle in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: what is $a^g$ any ways ??

Comment: I corrected the answer, indeed I just need the algorithm for $S_n$.

Comment: $a^g := g^{-1} a g$.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ have the same cycle type, then write down their cycle reps, and figure out the permutation that relabels the entries of the one to give the entries of the other.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $a=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots a_k\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & \ldots b_k\end{pmatrix}$, then 
\begin{align*}
gag^{-1} & =g\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots a_k\end{pmatrix}g^{-1}\\
& =\begin{pmatrix} g(a_1) & g(a_2) & g(a_3) & \ldots g(a_k)\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
So if you want 
$$\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & \ldots b_k\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} g(a_1) & g(a_2) & g(a_3) & \ldots g(a_k)\end{pmatrix}$$
then all you need to do is use the permutation $g$ which sends $a_i \to b_i$.
You can extend this argument when $a$ and $b$ are not just cycles but product of disjoint cycles.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the 2nd question, the GAP command is `RepresentativeAction`. For example:

```
gap> G:=SymmetricGroup(10);
Sym( [ 1 .. 10 ] )
gap> x:=(1,2,3)(7,5,4,9)(6,10);
(1,2,3)(4,9,7,5)(6,10)
gap> y:=(10,9,8)(7,6,5,4)(3,2);
(2,3)(4,7,6,5)(8,10,9)
gap> t:=RepresentativeAction(G,x,y);
(1,8)(2,10,3,9,7,6)
gap> x^t=y;
true
```

`RepresentativeAction` works for other actions as well, please see the GAP manual [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap41.html#X857DC7B085EB0539) for further details.